# How can I append id to whitelist.json so it will be added and the bot can read it without restart

Tags: json, discord, discord.py, whitelist

How can I append id to whitelist.json so it will be added and the bot can read it without restart, so when i append the id to whitelist.json the bot can directly read it without restart and let the new id use the bot? here's what I've tried

```
@bot.command()
async def whitelist(ctx, ids: int=None):
    data = {}
    for id in ids:
        data[id] = []
        data[id].append(id)
    with open('./whitelist.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)
```

and here's what's in whitelist.json if it will help:

```
{
    "Whitelist": [483686172221243402]
}
```

**Note:** I want the command let me add more than one id per time, and again i want the bot to access the whitelist.json and read the new data directly so the new id can use the bot

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json.dumps()` and write to the file like so:

```py
import json

@bot.command()
async def whitelist(ctx, ids: int=None):
    data = {}
    for id in ids:
        data[id] = []
        data[id].append(id)
    with open("whitelist.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data)) # write string to file using dumps.
```

now the next time you open this file the contents will be modified.